# Tomcat Start using docker command

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I am trying to copy(scp) the war to tomcat/latest/webapps and start the service using docker command.

I am able to copy the war but not sure what commands to use to start/trigger it.

Please let me know the docker commands which does the same thing as Tomcat Manager start button does.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't tomcat auto deploy the war when you copy it?

Comment: yes it is doing it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After ssh into the server, run below command

cat rate-service.war | sudo docker exec -i stay_rate_1 sh -c 'cat >
 /opt/tomcat/latest/webapps/rate-service.war'

and it works.